# Show that $T\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kv_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kTv_K$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

$T$ is a bounded linear operator on a normed vector space V.

(i) Assume that $w_k \rightarrow w$ in V as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Show that $Tw_k \rightarrow Tw$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

(ii) $\{v_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence V and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kv_k$ is convergent for some scalar sequence $\{c_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, show that
$$T\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kv_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kTv_k.$$

My problem is not showing (i), but Im having a hard time showing (ii). I have done this so far:

We know by definition that
$$v=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kv_k = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k.$$ This yields
$$Tv = T\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left(T\sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^N c_kTv_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kTv_k.$$
Is this true? Can I just replace the infinite sum by the limit? I feel like this is not the right approach.

Comment: That is the definition. An infinite sum is defined as the limit of the partial sums.

Comment: That is exactly the right approach. You apply (i) to the partial sums in (ii).

Comment: Thank you! That confirms my uncertainty!